# Equation describing electrons in a atom/ion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electronic-configuration

When not only 1 electron exist in the atom/ion the electrons of the atom/ion interact with each other and with the nucleus.

Do we solve this equations:

[image]

or this equation?

[image]

x is the position of a electron inside the atom/ion.

and we include the collective electric potential of the nucleus and all electrons inside the Hamiltonian?

Since the first equation will give different results than the second equation this will surely affect the shape of the orbitals and the chemical properties of the atom.

When do the different chemical properties become important enough?

Comment: It is complicated.

Comment: Bethe and Salpeter wrote a whole book on one- and two-electron atoms. A classic in quantum mechanics...

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two equations you posted? What are $x_1$, $x_2$, ... $x_n$, and $x$, supposed to mean? Are the Hamiltonians different (this seems to be implied, but not clear)? Do the $\Psi$'s represent different types of wavefunctions (again, seems to be implied, but not clear)?

Comment: x1,x2...xn are the positions of all the electrons of the atom

Comment: OK, but what about $x$ without a subscript, and $H$, and $\Psi$? Like, it's obvious that $H$ is some Hamiltonian and $\Psi$ is some wavefunction, but it's not obvious what Hamiltonian and what wavefunction it is, like is it single-electron or multi-electron? I suppose by $x_1$ you really mean a vector $\vec{x}_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$?

Comment: @orthocresol the Hamiltonians are different because they are for a different number of particles.

Comment: @orthocresol Exactly.

Comment: Sorry, but I asked a lot of questions to try and clarify what you're asking, and your responses don't entirely help. You need to explain all the terminology you're using, if your Hamiltonians (and wavefunctions) are different, then perhaps it's not a good idea to use the same symbol $H$ (and $\Psi$) in both equations? You should [edit] your question to include this detail, don't need to reply to me in the comments.

Comment: The Hamiltonian in the first equation is for  n particles while in the second equation it is for a single particle.

Comment: @orthocresol - I think what OP is saying is that the second version is similar to a DFT type approach - solving single electron equations while treating the rest of the electrons as a bulk potential field. Right?

Comment: Who's on first?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that we'd like to do the first, but solving the multi-electron Schrodinger equation is impossible, so we use variations of your second option (ie considering many separate one-electron wavefunctions) to get something that matches experimental data as closely as possible, even though we don't ever get an explicit form of the true multi-electron wavefunction.

Two of the most common approaches are 1) Hartree-Focke self-consistent field theory and 2) density functional theory (which I think is closer to what you have in mind). Both are much longer topics to explain than a short SE answer, but it's easy to find information on both in chemistry texts or online.